# Node crypto - unable to reverse encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

Why does this not print "hello"?

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('rc4', 'secret', '');
crypt = cipher.update('hello', 'binary', 'utf8');
crypt += cipher.final('utf8');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('rc4','secret', '');
data = decipher.update(crypt, 'binary', 'utf8');
data += decipher.final('utf8');

console.log(data); // prints e/l
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

utf8 is not a valid cipher.final() option, you want binary. Try this.

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('rc4', 'secret', '');
crypt = cipher.update('hello', 'utf8', 'binary');
crypt += cipher.final('binary');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('rc4','secret', '');
data = decipher.update(crypt, 'binary', 'utf8');
data += decipher.final('utf8');

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Nope. That throws an "AssertionError: Cannot change encoding" error

Comment: Sorry, didn't change cipher.update. Edited my answer, give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Woking code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var ecr = function(str)
{
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'passphase');
    var cryptedBuffers = [cipher.update(new Buffer(str))];
    cryptedBuffers.push(cipher.final());
    var crypted = Buffer.concat(cryptedBuffers);
    return crypted;
};
var dcr = function(str)
{
    var dcipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'passphase');

    var dcryptedBuffers = [dcipher.update(new Buffer(str))];
    dcryptedBuffers.push(dcipher.final());
    var dcrypted = Buffer.concat(dcryptedBuffers)
        .toString('utf8');
    return dcrypted;
};

console.log(dcr(ecr('hello test')));
```

Comment: Better to use IV version.